# How to automatically update database value when issue book in library management

Tags: c#

I want to make a library system in C#. In this system when a book is issued it should automatically reduce the book quantity in database. When `book quantity == 0`  there should be a message box showing "not available".

This is my code:

```
private void btnIssue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbResID.Text != "" && cmbMemID.Text != "" && cmbBookID.Text != "" && txtBkTitle.Text != "" && txtCategory.Text != "" && txtAuthor.Text != "" && txtIssueDate.Text != "" && txtActDate.Text != "")
    {
        SqlCommand Quantity = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblBookDetails where Book_ID = '" + cmbBookID.Text +"'");
        DataSet ds = Library.Select(Quantity);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (b > 0)
            {
                //a = a - 1;
                //int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                //label15.Text = a.ToString();

                SqlCommand update=new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblBookDetails SET Quantity=Quantity-1 WHERE Book_ID='"+ cmbBookID +"'");                          
                Library.ExecuteInsert(update);

                SqlCommand save = new SqlCommand("insert into tblBookIssue values(@ResID,@Member_ID,@Book_ID,@Issue_Date,@Act_Ret_Date)");
                save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResID", cmbResID.Text);
                save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member_ID", cmbMemID.Text);
                save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_ID", cmbBookID.Text);
                save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issue_Date", txtIssueDate.Text);
                save.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Act_Ret_Date", txtActDate.Text);
                Library.Insert(save);
                MessageBox.Show("Book Issued", "Book Issue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                clear();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("this book is not available");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FILL COLUMS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing SQL based off of text boxes is very unsafe and Prone to SQL injection attacks. Also, to follow Object Oriented program and make much cleaner code it would be advisable to make a Book object, I completed some code below which shows an example including the book incrementer. It would be better to make focused stored procs which execute gets for books and updates for book checkouts. You will have to turn your basic select into a stored proc, and write another proc which looks at the quantity and if quantity < 1 return 0 else return 1. Let me know if you need more info, this code should help you get rolling

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MockLibrary
{
internal class Book
{
    #region Constructors

    public Book()
    {

    }

    public Book(string resId, string memberId, string bookId, DateTime issueDate,     DateTime actRetDate)
    {
        this.ResId = resId;
        this.MemberId = memberId;
        this.BookId = bookId;
        this.IssueDate = issueDate;
        this.ActRetDate = actRetDate;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _ResID;
    private string _MemberID;
    private string _BookId;
    private DateTime _IssueDate;
    private DateTime _ActRetDate;

    public string ResId
    {
        get { return _ResID; }
        set { _ResID = value; }
    }

    public string MemberId
    {
        get { return _MemberID; }
        set { _MemberID = value; }
    }

    public string BookId
    {
        get { return _BookId; }
        set { _BookId = value; }
    }

    public DateTime IssueDate
    {
        get { return _IssueDate; }
        set { _IssueDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime ActRetDate
    {
        get { return _ActRetDate; }
        set { _ActRetDate = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    public Book GetBookByID(string resId, string memberId)
    {

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("put your db con string here"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetBookById", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = resId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = memberId;

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlDataReader  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Book newBook = new Book(rdr["ResId"].ToString(),rdr["MemberId"].ToString(),rdr["BookId"].ToString(),DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now);
                        return newBook;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("something went wrong");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public bool CheckoutBook(string resId, string memberId)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("put your db con string here"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckoutBook", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = resId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = memberId;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr["checkoutsuccessful"].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

when user returns a book:-

```
        MySqlCommand cm1;
        cm1 = new MySqlCommand("update addbook set bookquantity=bookquantity+1 where bookname='" + txt_bookname.Text + "'",con);
        cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```